# В чём разница между querySelector и getElementById?

Tags: javascript

Вопрос, возможно, слишком общий или не по теме, но мне интересно. Я видел, что кто-то использует `querySelector` для поиска элемента по id, а не по имени класса. Почему бы не воспользоваться методом `getElementById`, ведь он специально для этого и предназначен? `querySelector` выполняет это быстрее или как-то корректнее?

Comment: На самом деле побыстрее будет именно getElementById. А в целом, думаю, просто кому как удобнее. Или, может, прописано в правилах компании использовать чисто querySelector и querySelectorAll и не мучить лишние методы

Comment: мотивация такая - если Вы в какой-то момент передумываете использовать id и захотите по другому выбирать элемент - нужно просто поменять селектор, а не изменять имя вызываемого метода

Comment: @StrangerintheQ странная мотивация, в моей практике такой необходимости никогда не возникало. Да и переписать название метода — дело пяти секунд. И я использую getElementById и мне норм :)

Comment: @andreymal дело хозяйское, мне ближе querySelector

Comment: @andreymal и в случае обращения по id, я частенько испозьзую прямое обращение

Comment: Я стал в ответах на SO, где есть формы, использовать `querySelector(input[name="..."])`, как правило чтобы классы и `id` не писать ) Если кто-то хочет рассказать про быстродействие: пусть предоставит бенчи, мой ответ все равно будет один - отличные тесты. И дальше буду юзать `querySelector` `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @РустамГимранов поддерживаю :)

Comment: @РустамГимранов а стоило бы просто `form.inputname` вместо этой портянки писать

Comment: @andreymal это если есть `form`

Comment: @РустамГимранов вот тебе бенчи `https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/2488/0/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector` getElementById быстрее

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов, Значит отличий в основном нет, только селектор немного медленней, чем getElementById, но может обрабатывать в результате не только ид, но и классы и формы?

Comment: **В чём разница между querySelector и getElementById?**
https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-internals

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как показал тесты  [**бенчмаркинга**](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/2488/0/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector) `getElementById` почти в два раза быстрее чем `querySelector`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как  вы сказали отличий в основном нет, только `querySelector` немного медленней, чем `getElementById`, и может обрабатывать в результате не только **id**, но и классы  , атрибуты и т.д.

**querySelector**:Этот метод часто используется, когда мы заведомо знаем, что подходящий элемент только один, и хотим получить в переменную сразу его. [**Caniuse**](https://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector)

**getElementById**:Если в документе есть несколько элементов с уникальным id (что не правильно), то поведение неопределено. То есть, нет гарантии, что браузер вернёт именно первый или последний – вернёт случайным образом. [**Caniuse**](https://caniuse.com/#search=getElementById)

Также если у элемента есть **id** многие программисты используют прямое обращение через переменную, чтобы было меньше букв и проще было понять происходящее. Но предпочтительным методом является **document.getElementById.**

```
<h1 id="myTag"></h1>

myTag.innerHTML = "Какой нибудь текст"
```

Comment: синтетические тесты они такие коварные - https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/59870

Comment: наши тесты расходятся во много много раз

Comment: @StrangerintheQ куда не крути `getElementById` быстрее.

Comment: никто в этом и не сомневался

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да и может быть различие  миллисекундах в тестах.

Comment: Очевидно было бы предположить, что querySelector должен помимо поиска по селектору сначала распарсить селектор. Ни разу не видел миллионов селекторов в цикле чтобы делать подобные тесты.